What Are My Chances of Visitor Visa Approval Based on My Financial Situation and How Can I Improve?
I intend to apply for a visitor visa with a sponsor in London, UK. Considering that UKVI primarily focuses on my financial ties to my home country and the amount of funds in my name, what are my chances of approval based solely on my financial situation? I will submit two bank statements: one showing six months of transactions with an end balance of 0 (as I no longer use that account) and another showing three months of transactions with a balance of 1,100 euros. It’s worth noting that I don’t usually save my salary, as reflected in my old account, but for the past three months, I have saved my salary specifically for this visit. I plan to stay in London for four days, during which all expenses will be covered by my sponsor. I only intend to spend a small amount on shopping. What are your thoughts?
Old account: Final balance 0 (shows monthly deposit of salary)
New account: Final balance 1,100 EUR (shows monthly deposit of salary)
Additionally, my salary has recently been increased, and I also received a bonus, further reflecting my economic ties to my home country.

What’s your citizenship, and if different, where do you live? What’s the reason for the trip? What is the anticipated total cost of the trip? What is the reason for the sponsor to pay for you? What’s your relationship to the sponsor? What will they actually pay for (flight, accommodation, food, transport…)? What’s your monthly salary? What are your monthly expenses?

IMHO unless you have a strong travel history your chances of success are not high. See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e
